# Pycharm debugger, does not go deep enough : Django project. [ fairly new to python/Django ]

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I'm currently debugging my Django project [kind of first project in Django/python]. The debug 'Step Over' button in Pycharm seems to be going properly. However at a particular point, it does not go deep enough.

Below is the code with the debug point (commented that particular line).
***Please note, it's a properly working project, although I have trimmed down the codes (like skipping import statements, class definitions etc) here to make it as simple as possible to represent my question.***

File: `create_report_view.py` Here is where I have set the debug point.

```
from project.project_core.forms import BrandModelForm

def post(self, request):
    brand_form = BrandModelForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if brand_form.is_valid():                                # Debug point
        file_name_errors, csv_name_errors, file_name_alphanumeric_error = self._validate_data(brand_form)
        print("  And debug step goes on...  ")
```

So, the debugger skips what happens **inside** the `.is_valid()` call, where my validation runs, and jumps to next line in the above code. How do I force it to debug the `.is_valid()` method as well ?

### Dependent code blocks.

Below is the definition of my model, where i mention the `validators` in it.

File : `models.py`

```
from django.db.models import Model
from project.project_core.validators import ReportTypeValidator
class BrandModel(Model):
    report_model = models.ForeignKey(ReportModel, models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, db_index=True)
    review_file = models.FileField(upload_to='reviews/', validators=[ReportReviewValidator])
    number_of_reviews = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

File : `forms.py`

```
from project.project_core.models import BrandModel
class BrandModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BrandModel
        exclude = ('report_model',)
        labels = {
            'name': 'Brand Name'
        }
```

File :`validators.py`

```
from django.utils.deconstruct import deconstructible

ReportReviewValidator = UploadFileValidator(REVIEW_FILE_COLUMNS, CHARACTER_LIMIT_CONFIGS)

@deconstructible
class UploadFileValidator:

    def __init__(self, review_file_columns: List[str], character_limit_configs: List[CharacterLimitConfig]):
        self.csv_column_validator = CsvColumnsValidator(self.review_file_columns)
        self.char_limit_validator = CharLimitValidator(self.char_limit_configs)

    def __call__(self, field_file: FieldFile) -> None:
        row_list = self.csv_column_validator(field_file)
```

I want the debugger to reach the above block of code, i.e the class `UploadFileValidator`

What should I be doing for that ?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you need to put your breakpoint one line above and use "step into" to get into it:

```
def post(self, request):
    brand_form = BrandModelForm(request.POST, request.FILES)  # Debug point
    if brand_form.is_valid(): # Step Into this
        file_name_errors, csv_name_errors, file_name_alphanumeric_error = self._validate_data(brand_form)
```

Note that this will get you to the is_valid() method, which is django's way of checking if your form is valid. It is not going to instantly take you to your validator. You will have to navigate through the whole process of django's form validation, and at some point you will end up in your own validator. If you want to specifically get into your validator's code, put a breakpoint inside instead.

Comment: Nope. I just tried this. Debugger still doesn't take me to the UploadFileValidator class.

Comment: It is not going to instantly take you there, you are going to navigate through the whole process of django form validation, and at some point you will end in your own validator. If you want to specifically get into your validator, put a breakpoint inside instead.

Comment: It is not at some point. It is at that particular line the validation happens. But the debugger doesn't take me there, to the UploadFileValidator class.

Comment: You know that when calling `is_valid()`, the method is in turn calling other methods, right? It is not calling your validator directly, there are steps between. You said you had PyCharm, try to Ctrl+Click on `is_valid()` to see the source code, how far it goes and how complex it is. If you did things right, this method will call the validator you defined, but it is doing that for every validator of every fields of your form, aside from other things. This method is clearly not just calling your own validator. If you don't understand why, I invite you to read django's documentation on validation